# Can't get Chocolatey to download files

Tags: chocolatey

I am running Windows Enterprise 8.1. I am able to do the following on Windows Server 2008 R2, but I can't do it on Windows Enterprise 8.1. I have successfully installed Chocolatey and am trying to run "cinst poshgit". When I do, the program fails with the following message:

> Could not connect to the feed specified at 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'.

Below is the log file

```
20140401-13:21:22 [CHOCO] ################################################################################
20140401-13:21:22 [CHOCO] #                  Going Chocolatey on 2014-04-01 13:21:22Z                    #
20140401-13:21:22 [CHOCO] ################################################################################
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] Arguments: $command = 'install'|$packageNames='poshgit'|$source=''|$version=''|$allVersions=False|$InstallArguments=''|$overrideArguments=False|$force=False|$prerelease=False|$localonly=False|$verbosity=False|$debug=False|$name=''|$ignoreDependencies=False|$forceX86=False|$packageParameters=''|PowerShellVersion=4.0
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] Invoke-ChocolateyFunction is calling: $ChocoFunction='Chocolatey-Install'|@paramlist='@paramlist'
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] Running 'Chocolatey-Install' for 'poshgit' with source: '', version: '', installerArguments:''
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] Running 'Chocolatey-NuGet' for poshgit with source:''. Force? False
20140401-13:21:22 [CHOCO] Chocolatey (v0.9.8.23) is installing 'poshgit' and dependencies. By installing you accept the license for 'poshgit' and each dependency you are installing.
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] Installing packages to "C:\Chocolatey\lib".
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] Running 'Run-NuGet' for poshgit with source: '', version:''
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] ___ NuGet ____
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] Running 'Get-ConfigValue' with configValue:'useNuGetForSources'
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] Running 'Get-UserConfigValue' with configValue:'useNuGetForSources'
20140401-13:21:22 [DEBUG] After checking the user config the value of 'useNuGetForSources' is ''
20140401-13:21:23 [DEBUG] Value not found in the user config file - checking the global config
20140401-13:21:23 [DEBUG] Running 'Get-GlobalConfigValue' with configValue:'useNuGetForSources'
20140401-13:21:23 [DEBUG] After checking the global config the value of 'useNuGetForSources' is 'false'
20140401-13:21:23 [DEBUG] Running 'Get-UserConfigValue' with configValue:'sources'
20140401-13:21:23 [DEBUG] Running 'Get-GlobalConfigValue' with configValue:'sources'
20140401-13:21:23 [DEBUG] Using global sources
20140401-13:21:23 [DEBUG] Using '-Source "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/" ' as the source arguments
20140401-13:21:23 [DEBUG] Calling 'C:\Chocolatey\chocolateyinstall\nuget.exe' install poshgit -Outputdirectory "C:\Chocolatey\lib" -Source "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"  -NonInteractive -NoCache
20140401-13:21:24 [DEBUG]
20140401-13:21:25 [DEBUG] Caught 'Could not connect to the feed specified at 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'. Please verify that the package source (located in the Package Manager Settings) is valid and ensure your network connectivity.'
20140401-13:21:25 [CHOCO] Could not connect to the feed specified at 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'. Please verify that the package source (located in the Package Manager Settings) is valid and ensure your network connectivity.
20140401-13:21:25 [CHOCO] Command 'install' failed (sometimes this indicates a partial failure). Additional info/packages: poshgit
20140401-13:21:25 [DEBUG] Exiting with non-zero exit code.
```

Also, when I try to run any cinst commands in the system event viewer I get:

> A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 49.

Comment: What happens when you directly go to https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/ ?

Comment: In a browser I can go directly to https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/ and I see the xml file fine.  Last night, when I tried it away from my corporate firewall it worked fine.  I suspect that my corporate firewall is blocking it.  The weird thing is clients running Server 2008 r2 in the network can get it to work.

Comment: I'd be interested it know if it has to do with Win 8.1 "ENTERPRISE" or not. We have plenty of folks already using Win 8.1 or 2012 R2 and not seeing these issues.

Answer (score 8):

Open chocolatey.config and change https to http

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chocolatey>
    <useNuGetForSources>false</useNuGetForSources>
    <checksumFiles>true</checksumFiles>
    <virusCheck>false</virusCheck>
    <cacheLocation></cacheLocation>
    <ksMessage>false</ksMessage>
    <sources>
        <source id="chocolatey" value="http://chocolatey.org/api/v2/" />
    </sources>
</chocolatey>
```

Comment: Where is chocolatey.config located?  Update: found it at C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\config

Comment: Does this have an impact on the security of your downloads?

Answer (score 5):

Check the chocolatey status page: https://status.chocolatey.org/

Comment: Lately the community packages endpoint is generally Disrupted and only occasionally Operational. Do they do that on purpose?

Answer (score 4):

I got the exact same problem. Somehow it is related to network connectivity.

I just fired up fiddler to see what was happening, and when I enabled https connections everything began to work :).

This is on Windows 8.1 ENTERPRISE as well

In the eventviewer I'm having loads of SChannel errors (error code 49), see
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/10/06/ssl-tls-alert-protocol-amp-the-alert-codes.aspx